# Access two C# projects from each other

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I have two C# projects. Let's say **A** and **B**. I want to access windows forms in **B** using forms in **A**. And I want to access forms in **A** using forms in **B**.

**I added the second project as a reference. After that, I can Access files in B using A. But I can not add a reference to A from B.**

Actually, I have a login in a separate project and I want to show forms in other projects when a user logged in. Also when a user logged out from a particular form I want to show the login.

How can I solve this problem.?

Comment: Surely you can not reference projects to each other... This would result in cyclic dependency. Being in this situation explains that you need to rework on the application structure and design. If you can explain bit more about the use case and also share the project structure along with the relevant code... a better option can be suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since A -> B and B -> A Creates circular dependency, what I did was I added all the components to one project by copying and changing the namespace, then I created separate folders for each and every module. No references needed. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add a reference from **A->B** and **B->A** since it leads to a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). You can create a new module/project (Let's name it as **C**) and move common component/forms to that module/project. Then you can add references from **A->C** and **B->C**.